# Create new file for the text between the pattern

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have following pattern in my txt file:

```
./folder1/folder2/myfile.java
//java source line1
//java source line2
./folder1/folder3/myfile1.java
//java source line1
//java source line2
//java source line3
```

I want to split this file into like (if i issue cat command it should have source as per what's in the above one file):

```
cat ./folder1/folder2/myfile.java
//java source line1
//java source line2

cat ./folder1/folder3/myfile1.java
//java source line1
//java source line2
//java source line3
```

I am able to extract the content and file name using :

```
awk '/java/{flag=1;fileName=$0;next}/java$/{flag=0}flag' source.txt
```

But not able to redirect the code between to a file with different non existing folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following as i had to do it urgently.

```
#!/bin/bash
lastLine="2"
while read line
do
    if [[ $lastLine == "2" ]]
    then
       end=100
       lastLine=$line
       continue
    fi
    dir=$(dirname $lastLine)
    mkdir -p $dir
    source=$(echo $lastLine | sed 's/\//\\\//g')
    dest=$(echo $line | sed 's/\//\\\//g')
    sed -n "/$source/,/$dest/p" qpr_code.txt > $lastLine
    sed -i '1d;$d' $lastLine
    lastLine=$line
done < mytest.txt
```

Comment: one comment in fast scan: use `read -r line` otherwise, the backslash escaped characters will be interpreted with bash. (such `\n`).

Comment: Actually, always use `while IFS= read -r line` unless you have a specific reason not to. You also need to always quote your variables to disable globbing and word-splitting or you'll get bizarre failures based on your input file contents and file names in your working directory, and your sed commands will fail given various contents of your input file. Don't do this!

Comment: @EdMorton true! for avoid trailing space deletion ;)

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton for your valuable suggestions. I did completed the work and was a one time activity.

Comment: You're welcome. I strongly recommend you recombine all of your separate files and do a diff against the original because there is a high probability that your command modified some of the text as it was creating the files.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is something like (untested but will be VERY close if not fully working):

```
awk '
/^\/\// { print > file; next }
{ close(file); dir=file=$0; sub(/\/[^\/]+$/,"",dir); system("mkdir -p \"" dir "\"") }
' source.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably is here more elegant solution, but i would do it as:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[  -f "$1" ]] || { echo "Usage: $0 filename" >&2; exit 1; }
csplit -z -s -k -n4 -f _java_source. "$1" '/^\.\/.*\.java$/' '{*}'
for file in _java_source.????
do
    dir_file=$(head -1 $file)
    dir=$(dirname "$dir_file")
    echo "creating $dir_file" >&2
    mkdir -p "$dir" && tail -n +2 < $file > "$dir_file" && rm $file
done
```

Two step solution:

- in 1st step the `csplit` splits the input file at the pattern `./(anything).java` and creating files as `_java_source.0001`...
- and in the second step creates the final directories and files. Beware, it blindly accepts the pattern as folder/filename without any checks.

For `perl` users, (e.g. who has probably installed the `Path::Tiny` module)

```
perl -MPath::Tiny -0777 -lnE '$r=qr(\./.*?\.java);path($1)->touchpath->spew($2)while(m{($r)\n(.*?)(?=($r|\z))}gs)' < file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) and the help of some useful modules, like `File::Path` and `File::Spec`. The first one is used to create the directories like the shell `mkdir -p`, and the second one handles the path to extract the directories and the file to write to. The rest is to use a regular expression to check if a line ends with `.java` or not, and create the file or write to it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Path qw<make_path>;
use File::Spec;

my ($fh);

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    if (m/\.java\z/) {
        $_ = File::Spec->rel2abs($_);
        my $dir = File::Spec->catdir((File::Spec->splitpath($_))[0,1]);
        make_path($dir, { error => \my $e }); 
        if (@$e) {
            printf qq|Error creating path: %s\n|, $dir;
            exit 1;
        }   
        close $fh if defined $fh;
        open $fh, '>', $_ or die qq|Cannot open file: $_\n|, $_; 
    } else {
        printf $fh qq|%s\n|, $_; 
    }   
}
```

You can run it with the input file as argument, like:

```
perl script.pl infile
```

And a check for the result:

```
find ./folder1 -type f -iname '*.java' -exec head '{}' \+
```

That yields:

```
==> ./folder1/folder3/myfile1.java <==
//java source line1
//java source line2
//java source line3

==> ./folder1/folder2/myfile.java <==
//java source line1
//java source line2
```